# nativebase tabs dynamic tab flickering

Tags: react-native, tabs, native-base

I am using nativebase and dynamic tab rendering flickering.

```
<Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />}>
this.state.ifA ? 
{<Tab>
<Text>A</Text>
</Tab>: null}
{this.state.ifB ? 
<Tab>
<Text>B</Text>
</Tab>: null}
<Tabs>
```

Like this i have around 7 tab in tabs component which is render dynamically whenever get response from service.

Many times tabs flickering. Anyone have solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two props `initialPage` and `page`. Give an index of the tab that you want to render initially in these props. For example you want to render first tab at initially then :

```js
<Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />} initialPage={0} page={0}>
  { this.state.ifA ? (
    <Tab>
      <Text>A</Text>
    </Tab>
  ) : null }
  { this.state.ifB ? (
    <Tab>
      <Text>B</Text>
    </Tab>
  ) : null }
</Tabs>
```

Comment: yes that is added in my code and i am changing also when user click on another tab.

Comment: How you changing on user click ? Can you please add code for that ?

Comment: And Tab just contain text component or you have added something else in tab ? Can you please add proper related code ?

Comment: Can you please add some more code, like is there any useEffect method or some more replated code ?

Comment: I am getting similar issue : https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1198